# How do you interpret these routes? or more or more specifically, what is scope link?

Tags: networking, ip, route

I don't understand completely what these routes mean:

```
[root@samplehost ~]# ip route show
...#default route here

10.68.172.0/24 dev eno33557248  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.68.172.20
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno33557248  scope link  metric 1002
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno16782080  scope link  metric 1003

...#other normal routes here
```

Comment: It means that the network is valid and reachable through this device. 

You can read this in the documentation

[1]: http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-route.html

Comment: so, the same network is reacheable by two diferent interfaces in the same machine?

Comment: It's crazy because there is no interface with 169.254.x.x IP address

Comment: 169.254.0.0/16 is a link-local block. See RFC 3927 (though RFC 3330 is easier to memorize, and lists this and other special-use addresses).

Comment: @elmonkeylp, can you please edit the post and add the output of the command `ip addr show`